# delete text between two strings in files

Tags: string, text, replace, between

I'm trying to delete text between strings on different lines on unix so a solution using sed or awk would be ideal:

Sample of text:

```
xxx
   (abc)
   (def)

yyy
   (abc)
   (def)

xxx
   (abc)
   (def)

zzz
   (abc)
   (def)
```

I want to end up with :

```
yyy
   (abc)
   (def)

zzz
   (abc)
   (def)
```

A couple of things:

1. The lines I want to delete always begin with xxx
2. I want to delete until the next line starting with a string (i.e. not empty spaces) or until the next blank line.
3. I need a blank line between each bit of text as it is currently.
4. There are a number of blocks of text beginning with xxx and I want to delete each block.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i''  '/^xxx/,/^$/ d' myfile.txt
```

`sed -i''` updates the file in place; otherwise, the desired result goes to stdout.

Comment: This is awesome....thanks so much.  However I end up with a few additional blank lines in my text...any ideas how to get rid of them so I have just 1 blank line between each block?

Comment: Hmm ... the example you gave showed one blank line between blocks.
The command above deletes up to and including one trailing empty line at the end of an "xxx" block. FWIW it will also delete an "xxx" block with no trailing empty line, at the end of the file --- which looks possible given your example.  
Could you post an example input that produces extra blank lines?

Comment: Thanks for your response...appreciated....the same block above will produce a blank line at the top and then two blank lines between the yyy and zzz block.  I'm using GNU sed 4.2.1 on linux.  Not sure if it's something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

An awk alternative.

```
awk 'NR>4&&!(NR>=9&&NR<=12)' file
yyy
   (abc)
   (def)

zzz
   (abc)
   (def)
```

Skips first four lines and not print line 9-12.